# Remove all objects from a UIView

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using 2 UIView to draw different objects in a xib file. There is a need to clear the view before drawing new objects for some actions. Initially,when object types are smaller in number, I have been using this:

```
for (UILabel *btn in self.contentView.subviews)
{            
    if([btn isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        [btn removeFromSuperview];
    }        
}
```

But when I have multiple actions and objects of multiple types are to be drawn for each action, it looks bad coding to use this type of method. Is there some efficient method to do this?

Comment: `for(UIView *view in yourView.subviews){ [view removeFromSuperView]}`

Comment: Why do you feel , **looks bad coding to use this type** ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use this to remove all subviews, regardless of their class.

```
[self.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: Can u provide Swift version for this or shall i use :
     for subView in self.view.subviews {
            subView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use This For remove all object from a UIView

```
  NSArray *arr=view.subviews; //Your Vies's object.subviews

            for (UIView *view1 in arr)
            {
                [view1 removeFromSuperview];

            }
```